# How can i add bottom spacing in stackview swift4

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a stack view and as you can see in the picture I need to add some spacing in the bottom but i need the red background to be in the bottom as well so that it won't look weird.
i thought about creating antoher uiview and then adding the childs in the stackview to that view and then add that view to that stackview but i think that does't make sense.
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6egSR.png)
here's my code :

```
        let inputStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [enterMsgInput, sendLabel])
        inputStack.axis = .horizontal
        inputStack.distribution = .fillProportionally
        inputStack.alignment = .center
        inputStack.frame = CGRect(x: view.right , y: view.bottom, width: view.frame.width, height: 40)
        view.addSubview(inputStack)
        
        sendLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(70)).isActive = true
        sendLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(40)).isActive = true

        let bg = UIView(frame: inputStack.bounds)
        bg.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        bg.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        inputStack.insertSubview(bg, at: 0)
        
       inputStack.layer.masksToBounds = false
       inputStack.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
       inputStack.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
       inputStack.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
       inputStack.layer.shadowRadius = 3
          
        
        sendLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sendLabel.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        sendLabel.setTitle("Send", for: .normal)
        sendLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
        sendLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 40/2
        sendLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor().HEXtoUIColor(hex: "#AAAAFF")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you pretend to align the `inputStack` to the bottom of the safe area. You can do this easily using constraints, by constraining the `inputStack` bottom to the safeArea bottom constraint and by creating a background view (the red one) which is constrained to the top of `inputStack` and at the bottom to the bottom of the screen, like this:

```
let bg = UIView()
bg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
bg.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

let inputStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [enterMsgInput, sendLabel])
inputStack.axis = .horizontal
inputStack.distribution = .fillProportionally
inputStack.alignment = .center
inputStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

view.addSubview(bg)
view.addSubview(inputStack)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    inputStack.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
    inputStack.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
    inputStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
    inputStack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
    
    bg.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
    bg.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
    bg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputStack.topAnchor),
    bg.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),


    sendLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(70)),
    sendLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(40))
])
```

This will result in:
[image]

Comment: that's what i needed. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add a bottom constraint to your stack view relating to the safe area, then your stack view will be above the red view.